# How to change play framework dependency version

Tags: jar, playframework, dependency-management, activator

I want to change one of my library to the latest version. where to find the version of the dependency in play.

Comment: Could you add more details to the question, please? Which Play version are you using, what libraries are you trying to update, and what versions would you like to update them to?

Comment: I am using 2.4.3 version. Currently I am using jackson-mapper-asl.1.8.5 jar. I want to update this to latest version (1.9.13). In my .ivy2/cache/ folder I am having 1.8.5 version. How to update this dependency. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using activator to run the application. activator-launch-1.3.6.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can see a list of Play's direct dependencies by checking the `project/Dependencies.scala` file in the source code for that version of Play. For version 2.4.3, that file is here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.3/framework/project/Dependencies.scala

In the specific case of Jackson, the group ID and module structure changed between Jackson 1.x and 2.x. Play 2.4.3 is using Jackson 2.5.4. If your project depends on Jackson 1.8.5, this dependency isn't coming from Play, but from some other source.

You can use the [`sbt-dependency-graph`](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin to view the full tree of transitive dependencies and see where it is introduced.

To update to a newer version, you can add a direct dependency to your `build.sbt` with the desired version:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13"
```

This will override the version requested by other libraries; by default, sbt will use the greatest version requested.

However, there are a few things to keep in mind:

1. Jackson is composed of several sub-modules. If you are using several of these in the same project, including transitively, it's a good idea to use the same version of all of them. This might require adding additional dependencies to your project to keep them all in sync.
2. When upgrading dependencies in your application that are also used by other libraries it depends on, you'll need to consider backward compatibility. Jackson is not always fully backward compatible between minor versions, so if you update to a newer version of Jackson than what your libraries were designed to use, you might encounter problems at runtime.
3. Using both Jackson 1.x and 2.x in the same project is possible, since they have different group IDs and Java package names, but it may be confusing and error prone. If you can, it would be better to standardise on the Jackson version that is used by the Play Framework version you choose.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. having one more doubt, is it better to upgrade the play version then?

Comment: It’s always a good idea to use a recent Play version, @SathishKumarK. It’s not clear to me, though, whether that will directly help you with this issue. If Jackson 1.x is still being used in this project, maybe the best place to start is migrating the code that uses it to Jackson 2.5.4, which is already available due to Play’s dependency. Once that’s done, updating Play is a good next step.